# How to make a sticky Table of Contents with scroll Active highlighting in Elementor

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, elementor

I want to make a sticky table of contents the contents of which highlight when the corresponding heading is scrolled to. The current structure looks like this

[image]

This image contains a section with two columns in elementor. The left column contains the Table of content with the column having the class "left-column" and is made sticky using the Elementor Addon Contents Sticky Plugin.
The right column consists of the headings each with specific ids and is scrollable and has the class "right-column".
For the left column, I used HTML to group all the table of content items in a single class.
The HTML and CSS for the Table of Contents looks like this:

```
<div class="nav">
    <h2 ><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></h2>
    <h2 ><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></h2>
    <h2 ><a href="#section-3">Section 3</a></h2>
</div>

<style>
    .nav a:link {
        display: block;
        font-size: 14px!!important;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin-top: 8px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: right;
        font-family: Work Sans;
    }
    
    .nav a.active {
        color: black;
    }
</style>
```

And I used the following javascript to apply the highlighting functionality:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          // Select all headings in the right column
        var sections = $('.right-column h1, .right-column h2, .right-column h3, .right-column h4, .right-column h5, .right-column h6');
          // Select the table of contents section in the left column
        var nav = $('.left-column .nav');
          // Get the width of the left column
        var navWidth = $('.left-column').outerWidth();
        
          // Add an Intersection Observer to detect when a section is in view
        var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
            entries.forEach(function(entry) {
              if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                // Get the ID of the visible section
                var sectionId = entry.target.getAttribute('id');
                // Remove the "active" class from all table of contents links
                nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
                // Add the "active" class to the table of contents link that corresponds to the visible section
                nav.find('a[href="#'+sectionId+'"]').addClass('active');
              }
            });
        }, { threshold: 0.5 });
        
          // Observe each section in the right column
        sections.each(function() {
            observer.observe(this);
        });
        
          // Adjust the offset value to account for the width of the left column
        var offset = navWidth + 30; // Change the value of 30 as needed
        
          // Add smooth scrolling to table of contents links
        nav.find('a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
            if (target.length) {
              $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - offset
            }, 1000);}
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that the Table of Contents do not highlight in black colour as the corresponding headings are displayed on the right side. I am not able to understand where the code is failing.